# How do you write a for loop that chooses the first button in an array?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, variables

How can I add a for-loop to just pick the first buttons of the div where the `.mybuttons` class is located?

```js
var mapNumber;

const mybuttons = document.querySelectorAll('.mybuttons button');
mybuttons.forEach(mybutton => {
  mybutton.addEventListener('click', processClick);
});

function processClick() {
  window.mapNumber = this.id; // the id of the clicked button
}
```

```html
<div class="mybuttons">
  <button id="One">One</button>
  <button id="Two">Two</button>
  <button id="Three">Three</button>
  <button id="Four">Four</button>
  <button id="Five">Five</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You want to select button One in this case?

Comment: If you want the first, you can easily accomplish this with `const myFirstButton = document.querySelector('.mybuttons > button')`

Comment: `.mybuttons > button:first-child`, but that’s kind of weird. Are you going to be doing the same thing with other button numbers?